# css max-width=100% property for image having fluid parent container not working

Tags: html, css

I have fluid layout design. Every container has width set in percentage.

I was trying to give following css so that image larger than the parent container scale to fit in it and image smaller than container have their own width.

```
.imgClass {
  display:block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This is working fine in Chrome. But not working in Firefox and IE9.
I also put `width: 100%;` instead of `width: auto;` and that solve the issue for image larger than container. But if image is smaller than container. It get wider (to fit to 100%) and image get blurred.

Comment: Isn't that the CSS default?

Comment: What version of FF? This seem to be working fine on lastest Chrome, FF and Safari http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/mfweH/

Comment: http://wildfact.com/forum/topic-hello-to-all check this in firefox 29.0

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough, unless you have inline property dimensions on your image

```
.imgClass {
display:block;
 max-width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: No Its not working. I just modified the code as you suggested. But no luck, Here is link wildfact.com/forum/topic-hello-to-all. see the second post. and use firebug to see the css

Comment: if it doesn't work it might be because of inline CSS, javascript , or another rule with heavier selector. try to write max-width:100%!important; to check this rule can be applied

Comment: Tried, but not working. You can see yourself by using firebug. I tried lot but not working. However if i use some value instead of 100%, e.g 1000px. it works

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be enough as Johansrk said.

> But if image is smaller than container. It get wider (to fit to 100%) and image get blurred.

Absolutely, it will be blurred because the image is **smaller than container**.